Feynman Lectures - 100V/m in the air
Feynman suggests that:

There is a vertical electric field E of 100 volts/m in the air.

This voltage is in part maintained through the action of thunderstorms. The highest part of our atmosphere has a relatively high conductivity and the ground is negatively charged. Recently, it has been shown that lasers may be used to seed lightening, suggesting that it is possible to create regions of higher conductivity in the atmosphere.
If I made a conductor long enough would I be able to drain charge from the conductive top contact of the planet and discharge to the surface, say - driving a circuit?

The diagram in Feynman's book reproduced below, shows that a current will flow as there has to be a redistribution of charge.

However, the redistribution of charge will only occurs as the rod is moving and will not be efficient as the work done moving the rod would most probably be far larger than the amount of electrical energy generated.
